# How to filter child entity with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I would like to return dto with value 1, but only show child items that match the query. Is it possible to do it by querying the parent entity, or need to be done "manually" on child entity?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        List<Dto> dtos = new List<Dto>();
        var items = new List<Item>();
        items.Add(new Item(){ Value = 5});
        items.Add(new Item(){ Value = 6});
        
        var dtos2 = dtos.Where(a=>a.Items.Any(x=>x.Value == 8));
        
        dtos.Add(new Dto()
                 {
                      Id = 1,
                     Items =  items
                 });

        
        
        foreach(var item in dtos2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
            
            foreach(var item2 in item.Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item2.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

The DTO classes are

```
    public class Dto
    {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
    }
    
    public class Item
    {
    public int Value {get;set;} 
    }
            
}
```

Comment: Your code work, just care with `a => a.Items.Any...` , `a.Items` can be null and throw NullReferenceException.

Comment: @vernou check my question again.

Comment: @TheGeneral the problem is that that dto2 is empty when query doesnt match condition such as Items.Any(x=>x.Value == 8). In such case I want to return parent entity and empty Items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible without mutating the `Items` property or instantiating new `Dto` objects.

Mutational operations, whilst possible, shouldn't be attempted using LINQ which is designed for querying.

However, if you're happy with allocating new objects, you could take this approach:

```
var dtos2 = dtos.Select(a => new Dto
{
    Id = a.Id,
    Items = a.Items.Where(x => x.Value == 8).Tolist()
});
```

This has the benefit of keeping the original `dtos` unchanged.

Comment: Both solution do a.Items.Any(query) first which would return empty result since there is no child item of value = 8. But I see where are you going with this.

Comment: @mko Maybe I misunderstood. Does the parent list not need to be filtered?

Comment: Since condition at the moment is only on the child list, i want to retrieve a parent with only limited number of items in child list (based on condition)